# Two Images on the Right Side of Text

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I want two images to appear below each other on the right side of my itemized text but the code I am using pushes the images out of the slide. Kindly guide me how should I fix it?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multi-Photon Catalysis}
  \begin{columns}[A]
    \begin{column}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
    \item Hamitonian of Quantum Harmonic Oscillator:
\begin{align*}
    H= \hbar \omega (N + \frac{1}{2}) \hspace{0.5cm}; N= a^\dagger a 
\end{align*}
    \item \textbf{Number states or Fock states}.
    \begin{align*}
        N|n\rangle = n |n\rangle
    \end{align*}
 \item \textbf{Coherent States}:\footnote{Agarwal, G. S. (2012). Quantum optics. Cambridge University Press.}
  \begin{align*}
                \hat{a}|\alpha \rangle = \alpha |\alpha \rangle \hspace{0.5cm};\\ |\alpha \rangle= D(\alpha)|0 \rangle = e^{(\alpha \hat{a}^\dagger - \alpha^* \hat{a})}|0 \rangle
            \end{align*}
\item Equal Uncertainty States $\Delta X = \Delta P= \frac{1}{2}$
\end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{Images/CoherentStatePhaseSpace2.png}

  \includegraphics{Images/CS..png}
    \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `A` is not a valid option for the `columns` environment. It will cause an error during the compilation and after the error, latex will just syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.
- vertical space. You specify your first column to be `5cm` wide, but in this setting, there is not enough space to fit everything within the frame height and thus part of your text column will continue off frame. As the columns are by default vertically centre aligned, your images will be moved down by the same amount to still be centred with the text column.

You can make a couple of tweaks to get a bit more space so your text fits withing the frame height:

- make the first column a bit wider to avoid some line breaks.
- use `\footnote[frame]{...}` so the footnote will span the whole frame width and not just the column, this will avoid another line break
- use the `T` option for the `columns` environment so that your columns will be top aligned and a very full text column won't drag your image column down
- and as last point: only use the `align` environment if you are aligning multiline expressions, e.g. by their equal signs. Other then the "Coherent States", your expressions are only single-line, so they should use the `equation` environment instead of `align`. For the "Coherent States", you can use `align`, but you need to tell latex, where it should align the expressions by using `&` at the appropriate places.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multi-Photon Catalysis}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
    \item Hamitonian of Quantum Harmonic Oscillator:
\begin{equation*}
    H= \hbar \omega (N + \frac{1}{2}) \hspace{0.5cm}; N= a^\dagger a 
\end{equation*}
    \item \textbf{Number states or Fock states}.
    \begin{equation*}
        N|n\rangle = n |n\rangle
    \end{equation*}
 \item \textbf{Coherent States}:\footnote[frame]{Agarwal, G. S. (2012). Quantum optics. Cambridge University Press.}
  \begin{align*}
                \hat{a}|\alpha \rangle &= \alpha |\alpha \rangle \hspace{0.5cm};\\ |\alpha \rangle &= D(\alpha)|0 \rangle = e^{(\alpha \hat{a}^\dagger - \alpha^* \hat{a})}|0 \rangle
            \end{align*}
\item Equal Uncertainty States $\Delta X = \Delta P= \frac{1}{2}$
\end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
%  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}

  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX StackExchange.

Most likely you need to size your images to fit in the available space you have. The following works, where I've replaced actual images with black squares created by `\rule{1in}{1in}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \rule{1in}{1in}

        \rule{1in}{1in}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In your case, you could try `\includegraphics[width=1in]{...}` or `\includegraphics[height=1in]{...}` whichever produces a small enough image to fit.  Then try increasing the size until you reach an optimal solution.

If you want something more automatic you could try setting `width` and `height` to things like `0.5\columnwidth` or `0.3\textheight` so that their dimensions are calculated with respect to the frame size.

Comment: I tried using different values for width and height of the image but the image does not fit into the frame. It is partially inside the frame. Could you please do it with my code? :) I think that my code has equations and maybe that's causing the problem here.